# Belkin router SSID not visible

Tags: router, troubleshooting, internet

I have a Belkin N150 router and can't connect to the internet. Only the small blue WPS light is blinking. It's SSID is no longer visble to any devices. I can't even access it's router management page through wired connection from the router to a laptop.

Here's the last log that my router provided:

```
Belkin Log File Starts...

Tuesday, January 07, 14  10:28:23.660 - H: Wan connectivity check failed, no internet connection

Tuesday, January 07, 14  10:28:38.707 - L: User advised to restart modem

Tuesday, January 07, 14  10:28:38.707 - J: PPPOE failed: Unsupported Access Point

Tuesday, January 07, 14  10:28:48.553 - M: User advised to restart router

Tuesday, January 07, 14  11:22:10.310 - E: First router ping failed

Tuesday, January 07, 14  11:22:16.728 - E: Second router ping failed

Tuesday, January 07, 14  11:22:16.739 - M: User advised to restart router

Tuesday, January 07, 14  11:28:46.093 - H: Wan connectivity check failed, no internet connection

Tuesday, January 07, 14  11:29:01.146 - L: User advised to restart modem

Tuesday, January 07, 14  11:29:01.146 - J: PPPOE failed: Unsupported Access Point
```

Comment: Tried resetting the router with reset button? Check user manual for details

Comment: Yes, but it did not fix the issue. I've tried manually resetting the router to its factory settings but did not work.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments it seems you've tried a reboot of the router and resetting it to factory default settings and can't connect to it even from a wired connection. This is unrelated to the internet connectivity of the router as even without this you should still be able to access the router configuration page.

I would check that wired connection is using DHCP to be on the safe side but other than that I would suspect the device has failed permanently and start looking for the warranty documents!